# refresh and access token with node js and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

Whenever my access token expires, I want my refresh token to take over

my frontend code:

```
let token = Cookies.get("accessToken");
    let refreshToken = Cookies.get("refreshToken");

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session",
      data: {
        elementClicked,
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;
      console.log("response data from checkout: " + data)//!json.stringify is failing circuler
      if (data) {
        const sessionUrl = data;
        console.log("Session URL:", sessionUrl);
        window.open(sessionUrl);
        console.log("Window opened");
        
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid response data:", data);
      }
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if(error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        token = refreshToken
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        console.log("refreshToken:" + token);
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session",
          data: {
            elementClicked,
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("refresh token response: ", response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("refresh token response error: ", error)
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Error: ", error)
      }
    });
```

this is my backend code in the middleware file:

```
if (req.headers['authorization']) {
      token = req.headers['authorization'].trim().split(' ')[1];
      console.log("token from middleware: " + token);
    } else {
      console.log('token header is missing')
    }
    console.log("Token: ", token);
    // console.log("Body: " + req.body.token + "query: " + req.query + "Headers: " + req.headers)//! this is showing undefined
  
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    }
  
    try {
      let decoded;
      if(res.status(401)){
        decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET)
        console.log("decoded refresh secret: ", JSON.stringify(decoded))
      } else {
        decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        console.log("decoded access secret: ", JSON.stringify(decoded))
      }
      req.user = decoded;
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(401).send("Invalid token, this is the error message:" + err);
    }
  };
```

Once the access token expires I still get the `xhr.js:251     POST http://localhost:4000/api/payment/create-checkout-session 401 (Unauthorized)` error

I think it has something to do with my frontend logic. In the console, I still get that the decoded refresh secret worked, and it is still printing my refresh token, it's just not taking over as the main token once the access token expires.